# angular + d3 tickFormat using a string value for y

Tags: javascript, angularjs, d3.js, nvd3.js

I have the following chart config:

```
nv.addGraph(function() {
    var chart = nv.models.cumulativeLineChart()
        .x(function(d) { return d.x.getTime() })
        .y(function(d) { return d.y })
        .color(d3.scale.category10().range());

    chart.xAxis
        .axisLabel('Período')
        .tickFormat(function(d) {
            return d3.time.format("%m/%y")(new Date(d));
        });

    chart.yAxis
        .axisLabel('Rentabilidade')
        .tickFormat(function(d) {
            return (d * 100).toFixed(2) + '%';
        });

    d3.select('#profitability-chart')
        .datum(data)
        .transition().duration(500)
            .call(chart);

    return chart;
});
```

The problem is that every last point in chart shows a different formatted `y` value. For example:

> line "Foo" on chart:
>
> - last point shows "36%"
> - Inspecting the `data` array,
>
>   - y = 1.7205607426554128
>   - display.y = 0.3602803713277064

[Here](https://gist.github.com/lsmagalhaes/6056168)'s a sample of the data.

I don't know where this *display.y* comes from, and how this value is computed. I thought `d3.format` was changing the real value, so I've switched to a manual tickFormat, but the problem still exists.

PS.: I'm also using angular.js.

Comment: Could you show us the complete code and the data?

Comment: @LarsKotthoff, the sample is [here](https://gist.github.com/lsmagalhaes/6056168). I don't know if I need to post the function that generate that data, I double checked it and it's fine. Debugging the snippet on the post the value `display.y` is created only after `d3.select(...).datum(...)`.

Comment: `display.y` is computed by NVD3. I'm not entirely what you're trying to achieve. Is all you want to display 2 decimal places for the y axis labels?

Comment: @LarsKotthoff, I need that the chart displays "172%" both on the chart axis and tooltip, but it's not what happening right now. Instead, it shows "36%". How can I change it?

Comment: You need to use a different kind of NVD3 chart. The cumulative line chart is exactly that -- it displays the percentages of the total, i.e. it expects the numbers to be absolute values.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff, do you I can bind and event to be fired when I change the y-axis zero point?

Comment: There is no event generated for that.

Comment: Actually, I've [found a way](https://gist.github.com/lsmagalhaes/6063088) to do that. My current idea is get the current index and use it to compute some other things outside the chart.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Lars Kotthoff](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1172002/lars-kotthoff) answered in a comment. Basically, I was build my data this way:

```
{
    "key": "Fund 1",
    "values": [
        {
            "x": "1999-11-05T02:00:00.000Z",
            "y": 1
        },
        {
            "x": "1999-11-13T02:00:00.000Z",
            "y": 1.00342088549313
        },
        ...
    ]
}
```

Basically, my `y` values were actual percentages, calculated dividing by the first value (that's why the first value is 1).

What should really be done is give absolute values to the chart, like:

```
{
    "key": "Fund 1",
    "values": [
        {
            "x": "1999-11-05T02:00:00.000Z",
            "y": 120045.21
        },
        {
            "x": "1999-11-13T02:00:00.000Z",
            "y": 32521.01
        },
        ...
    ]
}
```

And NVD3 will compute all percentages.