# NVD3 CumulativeLineChart isn't rendering the right values

Tags: d3.js, nvd3.js

I'm using NVD3's [CumulativeLineChart](http://nvd3.org/ghpages/cumulativeLine.html) to render some financial data (daily quotes), for example:

```
2013-08-02    1.386317
2013-08-05    1.391471
2013-08-06    1.389597
2013-08-07    1.393294
2013-08-08    1.386240
2013-08-09    1.382552
2013-08-12    1.383685
2013-08-13    1.399916
2013-08-14    1.404787
2013-08-15    1.409127
2013-08-16    1.419608
2013-08-19    1.429470
2013-08-20    1.423128
2013-08-21    1.438342
2013-08-22    1.440490
2013-08-23    1.421211
```

So, if `2013-08-02` is the first point on the chart, the y-value is `0`. Every point after has its y-value based on this calc:

```
quote of day / quote of first day - 1
```

For example, the y-value of `2013-08-23` is `0.02517029`.

The problem is: our chart isn't plotting the right values - the correct value at the end should be 12%, but chart shows 7%.

[image]

I'm almost sure I'm not using the CumulativeLineChart the right way, but how can I fix it? I'm planning to switch to the simple line chart, but I don't want to lose some features of the current chart. Is there any way to setup a custom function to be used by NVD3?

To contextualize, [this](https://gist.github.com/lsmagalhaes/288d094e8c338a940b80) is our actual set of data. The first and last quotes of the chart are:

```
20120830 | 1.232551500
20130730 | 1.383957600
```

As I said before, the y-value of the last point should be `0.1228396`, or 12.28%.

Comment: You would have to provide the y values that designate the actual percentage, as in the example. Are you currently processing your data to do this?

Comment: @LarsKotthoff, I don't understand. I made another similar question before, and [you said](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17790062/angular-d3-tickformat-using-a-strang-value-for-y#comment25991954_17790062) that I need to pass absolute values, so cumulative chart will display the percentages, which is exactly what I'm doing here.

Comment: Sorry, that was a bit unclear. What I mean is that calculating the percentage in your case requires a formula that depends on the first quote of the day, i.e. something that NVD3 can't easily figure out itself. Are you currently passing in the data as is shown or are you doing some processing on it?

Comment: Ah, ok. And yep, I'm passing the data as shown here.

Comment: So how are these values calculated? Based on your description, I would expect the value for 2013-08-23 to be 1.386317 + 0.02517029 = 1.41148729.

Comment: These are raw values. The calculation for a certain date is `(quote of this date / quote of first date) - 1`. For example, the first date is 2013-08-02, so the value for 2013-08-23 should be `1.421211 / 1.386317 - 1 = 0.0251702`

Comment: Ok, so to show 2.5% for this value, it would need to be 1.386317 * 0.0251702 = 0.0348938 in the data you pass to NVD3, no?

Comment: Sorry, I understand nothing about what you've done. Using a simple line chart, `0.0251702`, which is 2.5%, is the actual value used by the chart, previously calculated by me.

Comment: If you're planning on using a simple line chart anyway, I would suggest just doing that and providing the actual values that should be plotted.

Comment: Nope, I want the cumulative line chart, because I can change the y-axis zero point (which is very useful to me). The problem is what I'm trying to explain (and I can be very confusing trying to): the chart should plot 2.5%, but it isn't.

Comment: Ok, I got that -- what I'm struggling with is to understand why. As I've said in my first comment, the values in the data should directly reflect the percentage and that doesn't seem to be the case. Do you maybe have a complete example somewhere?

Comment: I'll work to publish a plnkr with a more complete example. For example, if I pass the percentages (based on my demonstrated calc) to the chart, do you think it's going to work?

Comment: Can we proceed this conversation on email?

Comment: Sure, that's probably better. Fire away.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

unfortunately, the documentation for NVD3 is terrible and I've found that
it is
often best to have a look at the source code instead. For the cumulative
line
chart, the normalization is done at the very end of the file, in the
function
`indexify`. The relevant code is

```
line.values = line.values.map(function(point, pointIndex) {
  point.display = {'y': (lines.y()(point, pointIndex) - v) / (1 + v) };
  return point;
})
```

where `v` is the first value of the line. This is obviously different from
the
formula you're using to calculate your percentages. So you would have to
give it
values that would result in the correct numbers given the formula in the
source.

Alternatively, you could of course modify the NVD3 source to use the
formula you
need.